# How to get logs of Docker Swarm service that failed and is rolled back?

Tags: docker-swarm

I have a service that when I try to start it fails:

```
docker service update service_name --force
```

And that fails:

```
rollback: update rolled back due to failure or early termination of task 56zr0aubhjskjw7idhzidfoi1
```

I would like to look at the log output of the service - but I don't seem to have access to that:

```
$ docker service logs 56zr0aubhjskjw7idhzidfoi1
no such task or service: 56zr0aubhjskjw7idhzidfoi1
```

How do I find out the reason that a service failed?

Comment: That's bizarre. check `docker service ps service_name --no-trunc` perhaps there's a message there with more details.

Comment: I deleted the stack, recreated it and now it works. same configuration... so i don't know what the problem is